# Unable to add an iptables RULE

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, redhat

Please help guyz, I am not able to add iptables rule..

On the computer on which I have to login, Shoreline is installed.I know I can add rule to /etc/shoreline/rules but I decided to manually enter an iptable rule by typing:

```
/sbin/iptables -A local2fw -s 10.100.98.74 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

[FULL iptables-save output is here(before command)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7728421/save.txt) 
After I executed the command, [OUTPUT](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7728421/save_after.txt)

Then why am I not able to login using 10.100.98.74... I get connection refused error...
And I can login ssh using other ips listed in the rule...

Tell me what more info do u need.. 
What can be the probable cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can be the probable cause?

The most likely reason this isn't working is the order of the rules.

See:

```
-A local2fw -s 10.100.56.42 -j ACCEPT 
-A local2fw -j all2all 
-A local2fw -s 10.100.98.74 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

By issuing a -A local2fw your rule is being appended to that change.  But if you look the last rule on the chain before you add that rule sends everything to a different chain.  By appending that rule after the jump nothing gets to the rule.

You could trying passing `-I` option instead of `-A` to insert the rule at some position.

Comment: You are right.. That solved the issue. Thanx